print (only) line preceding a match
Consider a text-input that looks like this:
a
b
pattern
c
pattern
d
e
pattern
a
--
pattern
z

I would like to get only the lines that precede a match.
E.g. if my pattern is pattern, the output should read:
b
c
e
--

The obvious solution with grep -B1 does not work, as it will

include the matching line as well
add separators if there are multiple non-matching lines
E.g.

$ grep -B1 pattern
b
pattern
c
pattern
--
e
pattern
--
--
pattern

I probably could filter out pattern, but

i think this is ugly
it doesn't help with the -- separator

$ grep -B1 pattern test.txt | grep -v pattern
b
c
--
e
--
--

I obviously cannot filter out the separator --, as this might actually be the line i'm interested in:
$ grep -B1 pattern  test.txt | grep -v pattern | grep -v "^--$"
b
c
e

I guess some clever awk or sed trickery could help me, but I have no idea which...
The solution should run in a POSIX shell, with only standard tools installed (not even Python!)

With GNU grep: grep -Poz '.*\n(?=pattern)' file

Cool. Feel free to add it as a proper answer (explaining what it does)

With sed:
sed -n '
                N
  /\n.*pattern/ P
                D
'

Normally the pattern space in sed contains a single line, the current line of input. It's like a one-line window that moves through the input as lines come.
Here we start each cycle by trying to append the next line of input to the pattern space (N). We end each cycle by deleting the initial line of the pattern space (D). This way the pattern space is a two-line window that moves through the input as lines come.
Having the two-line window, we can easily detect when pattern is in the second line of the pattern space (/\n.*pattern/, where \n matches a newline character) and only then print the first line of the pattern space (P).
Details here: POSIX specification of sed.

nice. i have to admit i never really grokked multi-line sed-expressions :-)

Perl is usualy installed on all Linux, so, I suggest you this Perl one-liner:
This prints the previous line $p if the current line contains pattern then store the current line in $p. For each line of the input file.
perl -ane 'print $p if /pattern/; $p=$_' inputfile

Output:
b
c
e
--


Or the awk equivalent: awk '/pattern/{print p}{p=$0}' file. PS: for this case perl doesn't need -a .

nice. slightly preferring this over the sed-solution as it is a one-liner :-)

@umläute For the record: my sed solution is multi-line for readability, it can as well be sed -n 'N;/\n.*pattern/P;D'. I don't mind my answer not being accepted, I'm just noticing that: (1) Being a one-liner is usually just about the form, as you can often fit even relatively complex script in one line. (2) Nowhere in the question there is any information that you prefer a one-liner. (3) There is the requirement that "the solution should run in a POSIX shell, with only standard tools installed (not even Python!)". sed and awk are in the POSIX standard; perl (like python!) is not.

fair enough; for my taste i still find the perl expression more readable (I never thought I would say that of a perl snippet)
